# Swapping elements in Edit1

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

I have a `Edit1` where you can type numbers like `2 20 10 -3` and when you click the `Button1` it brings out max and min numbers max = 20 min = -3.
Tried to make so when i bring out the numbers it swaps the `min` and `max` numbers in `Edit1` like `2 -3 10 20` i tried it in my ways but the other entered numbers change place.
I tried many ways:

```
 Edit4.Text:= (inttostr(min)+' '+ inttostr(max));
```

but it overwrite the other numbers.

Then i tried to use

```
maxnumb := Edit4

Edit4.Text  := StringReplace(maxnumb, inttostr(max), inttostr(min),
                          [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]); 

Edit1.Text  := StringReplace(maxnumb, inttostr(min), inttostr(max),
                          [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

But it only swaped the 1st number and when i clicked the `Button1` again it swaped the second number.

Code without the attempts to swap:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  oSL: TStringlist;
  s, ss: string;
  a: array [1 .. 15] of integer;
  i, j, k, p, code: integer;
  max, min: integer;
  before, after: string;
begin
  s := Edit1.Text;
  s := concat(s, #32);
  i := 0;
  while Length(s) > 0 do
  begin
    i := i + 1;
    p := pos(#32, s);
    ss := copy(s, 1, p - 1);
    Val(ss, k, code);
    a[i] := k;
    delete(s, 1, p);
  end;
  // Max
  max := a[1];
  For j := 1 to i do
    if max < a[j] then
      max := a[j];
  // Min
  min := a[1];
  For j := 1 to i do
    if min > a[j] then
      min := a[j];
  // Put out Max/Min
  Edit3.Text := IntToStr(max);
  Edit2.Text := IntToStr(min);
end;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, it is unclear: swapping the min and max value in `2 20 10 -3` does not return `2 -3 20 10` but `2 -3 10 20`.

Comment: And for solving this, stop your StringReplace attempts. Just parse all numbers from the Edit.Text, do your stuff on an array of integers, the concatenate them all back into your Edit.text

Comment: what type is maxnumb ? if it is a string then the first line "maxnumb := edit4" will not compile.  If it is a Editbox then the stringreplace will not compile. Check that you have the correct code in your question please

Comment: Yeah the maxnumb was a string and i will try to do things without the stringreplace.

Comment: Now im getting  a error unit1.pas(72,23) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "CompareReal" `function CompareReal(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  // make use of the comparer in unit Math
  Result := CompareValue(StrToFloat(List[Index1]), StrToFloat(List[Index2]));
end;      `

Answer (score 1):

```
uses
  Types, StrUtils;

function Arrange(const AEditFrom, AEditTo: TEdit): Boolean;
var
  _StrArr: TStringDynArray;
  i: integer;
  _IntArr: array of integer;
  _IntValue: integer;
  _Min: integer;
  _Max: integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  if not Assigned(AEditFrom) then
    Exit;
  if not Assigned(AEditTo) then
    Exit;

  _StrArr := SplitString(AEditFrom.Text, ' ');
  SetLength(_IntArr, Length(_StrArr));

  for i := 0 to Length(_StrArr) - 1 do
  begin
    if not TryStrToInt(_StrArr[i], _IntValue) then
      Exit;

    _IntArr[i] := _IntValue;
  end;

  AEditTo.Clear;
  _Min := _IntArr[0];
  _Max := _IntArr[0];
  for i := 0 to Length(_IntArr) - 1 do
  begin
    if _IntArr[i] > _Max then
      _Max := _IntArr[i];

    if _IntArr[i] < _Min then
      _Min := _IntArr[i];
  end;

  AEditTo.Text := StringReplace(AEditFrom.Text, ' ' + IntToStr(_Min),
    '...' + IntToStr(_Max), [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

  AEditTo.Text := StringReplace(AEditTo.Text, ' ' + IntToStr(_Max),
    ' ' + IntToStr(_Min), [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

  AEditTo.Text := StringReplace(AEditTo.Text, '...', ' ',
    [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not Arrange(Edit1, Edit2) then
    ShowMessage('Something went wrong. List contains not a integer?');
end;
```

Test: **2 20 10 -3**, Result: **2 -3 10 20**

Comment: As soon as i use the code the identifier SplitString is not found

Comment: `SplitString` should be found in this unit as shown in the answer: `System.StrUtils.SplitString`